# How to make a lightweight scrolling menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a scrolling menu just like this site : http://www.dsebd.org/, the menu which is scrolling horizontally from right to left.

This menu needs to be updated, say, every 20 or 30 seconds. I want to make this menu as light as possible. I was thinking about using jquery, but since I am a beginner I don't know how to use it, or even from where to get started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [jQuery Marquee](http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/), here's a demo: http://remysharp.com/demo/marquee.html.

For updating the content at set intervals without reloading the page you're looking at AJAX requests using the [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method.  I would recommend [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) for simple data retrieval for updating your pages.

jQuery has it's own [getting started guide](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery) and [visualjquery.com](http://www.visualjquery.com/) is a resource I constantly use as an API reference.

Hope that helps.